# how to get information from a message sent with the graph client

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to save information from a message so I can send a reply

I'm sending the message with the code from the docs:

```
const mail = {
    subject: "Microsoft Graph JavaScript Sample",
    toRecipients: [
        {
            emailAddress: {
                address: "example@example.com",
            },
        },
    ],
    body: {
        content: "<h1>MicrosoftGraph JavaScript Sample</h1>Check out https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript",
        contentType: "html",
    },
};
try {
    let response = await client.api("/me/sendMail").post({ message: mail });
    console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

It works perfectly but the response is a status code and when I'm trying to send a reply I have to provide the ID of the message, so how can I get the id of a sent message to be able to reply to it?

Comment: That's the expected behavior take a look at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3766 which has some solutions

Comment: @GlenScales I was worried about not coming up with a solution, I tried it and it worked perfectly, thank you very much